# How can I let my output be printed in a single string instead of seperate letters?

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

So I wrote this code to get every single row in a grid

```
def rows(test):
    r = []
    for x in test:
        r.append(x)
    return str(r)
```

the grid is this btw

```
test = [["r","a","w","b","i","t"],
        ["x","a","y","z","c","h"],
        ["p","q","b","e","i","e"],
        ["t","r","s","b","o","g"],
        ["u","w","x","v","i","t"],
        ["n","m","r","w","o","t"]]
```

and after running `rows(test)`, I get this

```
[['r', 'a', 'w', 'b', 'i', 't'], ['x', 'a', 'y', 'z', 'c', 'h'], ['p', 'q', 'b', 'e', 'i', 'e'], ['t', 'r', 's', 'b', 'o', 'g'], ['u', 'w', 'x', 'v', 'i', 't'], ['n', 'm', 'r', 'w', 'o', 't']]
```

but I want it to be

```
 [['rawbit','xayzch','pqbeie','trsbog', 'uwxvit', 'nmrwot']
```

What should I change??

Answer (score 1):

Use `.join`:

```
def rows(test):
    r = list()
    for row in test:
        r.append("".join(row))
    return r

>>> rows(test)
['rawbit', 'xayzch', 'pqbeie', 'trsbog', 'uwxvit', 'nmrwot']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `''.join()` like below:

```
>>> lst = [['r', 'a', 'w', 'b', 'i', 't'], ['x', 'a', 'y', 'z', 'c', 'h'], ['p', 'q', 'b', 'e', 'i', 'e'], ['t', 'r', 's', 'b', 'o', 'g'], ['u', 'w', 'x', 'v', 'i', 't'], ['n', 'm', 'r', 'w', 'o', 't']]
>>> list(map("".join, lst))
#OR
>>> [''.join(l) for l in lst]
['rawbit', 'xayzch', 'pqbeie', 'trsbog', 'uwxvit', 'nmrwot']
```

If you want as `function`:

```
def rows(test):
    # return [''.join(t) for t in test]
    # Or
    return list(map(''.join, test))
```